# Laravel ignoring multiple type of objects in query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, filtering

I'm trying to ignore specific types of objects in the query. there are types where I have banned or deleted data which I don't want the user be able to find. my query looks something like :

```
$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('content', 'like', '%' . $request['content'] . '%')
        ->where('isfutured', '!=', '0')
        ->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

But now I also want to not get the data with `isfutured` of `4`. how do I do that? or can I somehow prevent these in the Post model and do my regular Eloquent query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using query builder
>   for multiple condition used [whereIn](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#where-clauses) or whereNotIn

```
$isfutured = [0,4]; // add in array which did not want to get 

$posts = DB::table('posts')->where('content', 'like', '%' . $request['content'] . '%')
        ->whereNotIn('isfutured', $isfutured)
        ->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

> using elequent

```
$posts = Post::whereNotIn('isfutured', $isfutured)->where('content', 'like', '%' . $request['content'] . '%')->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

Comment: Oh, that is just what I have been trying with rawsql and it's a lot more dificult, I somehow managed to write this with mysql, but immideatly replaced with this.